# How can I duplicate a line of code multiple times in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there's a shortcut to duplicate a selected text:

To Copy Up - `shift`+`alt`+`up`

To Copy Down - `shift`+`alt`+`down`

But how can I do if I need to duplicate it, say, 33 times? Is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: This is fairly easy to implement as an extension, I'll make the extension soon - I have it working already as an addition to another extension but it should stand alone.

Comment: @Mark Having an extension like that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly fast way to achieve this is to create your 33 (or however many) lines in your editor, then use the multi-line cursor (hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> then use your mouse to select the lines you want the cursor to include), and then paste your text, like so:

[image: paste lots of lines using multi-cursor]

Comment: frank question: if you need to start by holding down keys to create the new lines, how is this faster than just copying and holding the key to paste the same line that same number of times. seems to me like this is actually _slower_ than that.

Comment: @starball I guess it _maybe_ at least offers slightly more control this way.  Really this method or the snippet answer I don't see being all that much faster, depending on how much pasting you need to do.  I question why you'd need to do such a mass pasting amount to begin with, but I guess it has some use cases.  Based off the question context, I don't think the number is a fixed amount either (33 is a weird fixed amount otherwise).  If pasting over existing text, then this is probably the fastest, as you can also use the multiline cursor to highlight the text and paste. No new lines needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you might have to do this often, you could make a code-snippet for this. Maybe one that copies 10 rows at a time.

```
{
    "Duplicate 10 lines of code at once": {
    "prefix": "dup",
    "body": [
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1",
        "$1"
    ],
    "description": "Copy the code, type \"dup\", then paste 10 lines of code at once."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of times is something that is fixed and that you will often reuse, you can write a keyboard shortcut using [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands), or use [the snippet approach from Joshua's answer](/a/77360409/11107541) (I'd add that you might also be interested in the various [snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) such as `TM_LINE_INDEX`, `TM_LINE_NUMBER`, `CURSOR_INDEX`, `CURSOR_NUMBER`).

If the number of times is variable, [use the multi-cursor approach from Timothy's answer](/a/77360517/11107541). But I question how much faster this is than just holding down the keyboard shortcut to duplicate the line, since you have to create new empty lines first (which presumably involves holding down the <kbd>enter</kbd> key or some other keyboard combination.

If you're a Vim person, you could use the VS Code Vim extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup> and use Vim keyboard things (Ex. `yy42p`).

There might be an extension that allows to you do something similar to the Vim thing except without being a whole Vim extension, but I'm not aware of it. I'd suggest searching "duplicate line" or "clone line" in the extension marketplace / the Extensions View's search bar.

Another hack could be to open a new file in a language mode where Emmet is supported, such as a new HTML file, and then type `{your text goes here}*N` ([Emmet multiplication](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#multiplication)), where "N" is the number of lines you want, then trigger suggestions and accept the Emmet abbreviation expansion suggestion, and then select all and cut from that new editor, close the new editor, and then paste it into the place where you actually wanted that text to go. If you need some sort of incrementing numbering in the text, you might also be able to make use of [Emmet's item numbering syntax](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#item-numbering) ("`$`").

Comment: @amedina yeha that's a good idea. not sure why I didn't write that initially. maybe I tried it and did it slightly wrong. I've edited the answer post to mention that now.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an extension, [Repeat Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.repeat-commands), to do this in a more automated way.

Here is a sample keybinding:

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+r",                           // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "repeat-commands.runSequence",
    "args": {
      
      // "preCommands": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      
      "commands": [        
        "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction"    // command ID from Keyboard Shortcuts
      ],

      // "repeat": 5,                     // hard-code a number
      "repeat": "${getRepeatInput}",      // get the number at runtime from the user
      
      // "postCommands": "editor.action.insertLineAfter"  // last file/line created
     
    }
  },
```

You can repeat multiple commands.  And you can run multiple commands before and after the repeated sequence runs.  Demo:

[image: repeat commands demo]

---

As the README mentions you can also use vscode extension api's as "commands" (but this feature is still being finalized at the moment).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Visual Studio Code does not provide built-in functionality to automatically duplicate code a certain number of times.